# I cant clean up tomcat catalina.out

Tags: linux

I am unable to clear the catalina.out log file generated by the running Tomcat. When I first cleared it using `> catalina.out`, it immediately became its original size.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVp2e.png)

I tried

```
> catalina.out
echo > catalina.out
```

Comment: What is your _question_?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.